# Google Spreadsheets: Alternating Background Color on Value Change or By Group?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

there are **lots** of topics about Conditional Formatting in Google Spreadsheets, but not one like what I'm looking for.

All I want to do is set an alternating background color based on the value changing in a column.  For example:

[image: Alternating colors for value change]

If there isn't an easy way to accomplish this, does someone know what I'd write for the conditional formatting formula?

The values will always be consecutive - the idea is that the coloring is simply a visual aide for when a new value is up.

If you're curious, I have a list of system types and their power consumption numbers - I would simply like to have a color demarcation for when the system type changes to the right off-screen.

Comment: Are the unique values always going to be concecutive?  Like would you ever see `ValueA` appear again in perhaps row 16?  And if so would you want that to be colored or left white?

Comment: I'll answer this by editing my post - thanks for the question!

Comment: @Locane did my answer fit?

Answer (score 46):

There's a way to do this without adding any extra rows or columns. Make a conditional formatting rule and for the "custom formula" put:

```
=iseven(match($A1,unique($A$1:$A$15),0))
```

The way this works is:

1. `unique` produces the list ValueA,ValueB,ValueC,ValueD,ValueE
2. `match` looks for each value (starting with A1) in that list, note that the search option `0` is required if your values are not sorted. `match` returns the index of the matching value
3. `iseven` applies alternating row coloring based on the matching index

Comment: This worked for me after I replaced the commas with semicolons, i.e. `=iseven(match($A1;unique($A$1:$A$15);0))`.

Comment: worked for me as-is. great solution @nonagon -- there was another article elsewhere but needed hide rows & columns... but this solution is simple and works beautifully. thanks very much!

Comment: is it possible to use LEFT or MID to pull just a substring from the range specified in "unique"? (Eg. I want alternating colors based on changes in the first 2 characters)

Comment: I had to adapt it to `=iseven(match($A2,unique($A$2:$A$1000),0))` but then it worked, since I was not considering the first row in my formatting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works great.
Just a caveat for sheets with 30K rows and about 6K unique values, the conditional formatting takes about an hour to complete. May be my machine is not powerful anymore. Also, reloading the sheet, the formatting is gone, it tries doing it again. Any suggestion here?

Answer (score 4):

I Added an additional column with the following formula: =IF($A2=$A1,$D1,$D1+1)

A2 since I have a header row
D since this is the additional column

than conditional formatting on with the following formula: =isEven($D1)

Answer (score 2):

## 0 / 1

Please try this formula on B1:

`={1;ArrayFormula(IF(OFFSET(A2,,,COUNTA(A:A)-1)<>OFFSET(A2,-1,,COUNTA(A:A)-1),1,0))}`

will add one's when new value in a row occurs.

---

## Counter

Next formula will make a counter for values in A:A.

Paste it in C1:

`ArrayFormula(SUMIF(ROW(OFFSET(B1;;;COUNTA(A:A)));
"<="&ROW(OFFSET(B1;;;COUNTA(A:A)));OFFSET(B1;;;COUNTA(A:A))))`

---

## Formating

Conditional formatting on range `A:Z` with the following formula: `=isOdd($C1)`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Easiest for me seems to be clear formatting from and select ColumnA and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=and(A1<>"",isodd(counta(unique($A$1:$A1)))=TRUE)
```

Then select formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

(From [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112088/60716).)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see this working is to make a new column.  This can be hidden if you want.

Throw this formula in any new column and autofill down:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A1<>INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1),IF(INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+64)&ROW()-1)=0,1,0),INDIRECT(CHAR(COLUMN()+64)&ROW()-1)),1)
```

Change A1 as needed to the start of your data.  You can also replace the `INDIRECT(...)` with offset but then you have to tell it what column you put the formula in.  So to give an example doing it that way; if you put it in column B:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A1<>INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1),IF(OFFSET(B1,-1,0)=0,1,0),OFFSET(B1,-1,0)),1)
```

This formula gives us a column of 0's and 1's that will tell us either to make the background colored or leave it white.

So in your conditional formatting just apply it to the desired range and use "Custom formula is":

```
=$B1
```

Chose formatting as desired

Answer (score 1):

the most reliable would be to use this formula:

```
=ISEVEN(SUMPRODUCT(--(A$1:A1<>A$2:A2)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks about this answer. Can you, please, elaborate why this is the most reliable formula and how it works? I'm really interested. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For an explanation of how SUMPRODUCT works: https://exceljet.net/functions/sumproduct-function