# Change cell value based on group of data

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Is there a way to change the color of a GROUP of cells, alternating between 2 colors? Example:

[image]

The data will always be sorted alphabetically, this is needed in order to make it easier to take a quick look on the table and see a group of data, and when a new group starts.

P.S: The table has thousands of rows with different groups of data, so conditional formatting by value is not an option.

Comment: Conditional formatting seems like it'd meet that need . . . just setting the trigger value to be B or D or F . . . sorting wouldn't matter.

Comment: The table has like ... thousands of group data ... conditional formatting by value would take forever :-(

Comment: Oh, I think I get what you're saying now. You want alternate row formatting no matter the value/number of rows. Just flip back and forth every time the group changes.

Comment: I think this covers it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268451/google-spreadsheets-alternating-background-color-on-value-change

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **@Tom Woodward**, the link you provided did the trick for me :-)

[Google Spreadsheets: Alternating Background Color on Value Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268451/google-spreadsheets-alternating-background-color-on-value-change)