# How would I alternate row colors whenever a value changes in any column?

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to get Google Sheets to alternate row colors whenever any cell in the row is different from the cell above it (within a specified range).
For instance:

[image: example image]

I found a few related solutions ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268451/google-spreadsheets-alternating-background-color-on-value-change) for example), but they all base the alternation on only one column's changes; the `MATCH` function only applies to a one-dimensional range.

Is there any way to accomplish this with multiple columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ISODD(MATCH($A2&$B2&$C2&$D2,UNIQUE($A$2:$A&$B$2:$B&$C$2:$C&$D$2:$D),0)))
```

[image: 0]